# Where on the Google Apps dashboard can I find the Google Apps Domain Verification Code?

Tags: dns, google-apps

I am switching nameservers from mediatemple to enom, and need to set up a handful (15) subdomains that each have their own have google apps account. I have been able to set up the MX records and all is well on that front, but unfortunately the CNAME records I currently use for verifying the domain won't work because enom only allows 15 (!!) host records total. It does allow plenty of TXT records and MX records, so I would be ok if I could switch to the more modern TXT record method for verifying the domains for google apps. But the TXT verification code looks different than the CNAME I have for other domains and I have not been able to find it anywhere in google apps or in their help system. It's been frustrating,

Where can I find the TXT verification code? Or do I have to wait for google to find out it's not verified to be able to get in and do the txt verification?

Would be very grateful for any advice. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a domain has been verified via CNAME, you can remove the record and replace it with the next one for another subdomain. It does not need to remain on the account as it's not checked after the initial verification.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! Much appreciated. Are you sure it can be removed? Does Google not check the verification periodically to make sure you still own it? Can you back up what you say with a link to google's help or some other trusted online source?

Comment: I know for sure they currently don't check after the initial verification but there's no documentation that says this AFAIK (source: worked for Apps Enterprise Support for a few years).